# Suppose $x,y,u\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x<y$ and $u\neq0$. Show there is $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying: $x<ru<y$

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about the following proof?

Suppose $x,y,u\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x<y$ and $u\neq0$. Show there is $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying: $x<ru<y$

I have tried using a form of the Archimedean property but I can't seem figure out how to have it apply from the upper and lower inequalities.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The inequality $x<ru<y$ is satisfied if and only if the inequality $\frac xu<r<\frac yu$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon =  y-x$. Then, by the Archimedean property, there is a $n$ such that $n \epsilon > r$. Any interval of length $> r$ contains an integer multiple of $r$, so $(nx, ny)$ contains an integer, say $mr$. Then, $r (m/n) \in (x, y)$.